# Unwanted data showed by crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, formula

i'am using this formula for parameters (record selection) :

```
if {?customPort}  <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.port} = {?customPort};
if {?airlin} <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.airlines} = {?airlin};
if {?hal} <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.hall}={?hal};
if (hasvalue({?tim})) then {ArrivingTrips.arrivalTime}={?tim};
{?d1} = {ArrivingTrips.arrivalDate};
```

the problem now, crystal report just looks at d1 and dosent care for another parameters even if the "if" expression is true so it shows unwanted data, why that ?

is it wrong syntax ?

**Note** : i send the parameters values by my vb.net code, not by Crystal parameters input panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local timevar t;
local stringvar air;
local stringvar port;
local stringvar halll;
if {?tim} <> "" then t:= ctime({?tim}) else t:= ctime({ArrivingTrips.arrivalTime});
if {?airlin} <> ""  then air:= {?airlin} else air:= {ArrivingTrips.airlines};
if {?customport}  <> "" then port:= {?customPort} else port:= {ArrivingTrips.port};
if {?hal} <> "" then halll:= {?hal} else halll:= {ArrivingTrips.hall};

{ArrivingTrips.airlines} = air and {?d1}= {ArrivingTrips.arrivalDate} and port={ArrivingTrips.port} and halll = {ArrivingTrips.hall} and (t)=ctime({ArrivingTrips.arrivalTime});
```

This is the solution, now , when "if condition" returns false result, report will care only for true conditions because the false one will will return the same value of a field so it's like no condition :)

Thanks for every one tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
({?d1} = {ArrivingTrips.arrivalDate})
AND (If {?customPort}  <> "" Then {ArrivingTrips.port} = {?customPort} Else TRUE)
AND (If {?airlin} <> "" Then {ArrivingTrips.airlines} = {?airlin} Else TRUE)
AND (If {?hal} <> "" Then {ArrivingTrips.hall}={?hal} Else TRUE)
AND (If (hasvalue({?tim})) Then {ArrivingTrips.arrivalTime}={?tim} Else TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your selection formula as single statements, so only the last statement in line gets evaluated. You should also have an "else" for each "if" condition, otherwise your statements will be prone to error and may show undesired data.

```
(if {?customPort}  <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.port} = {?customPort} else {other.condition}) OR
(if {?airlin} <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.airlines} = {?airlin} else {other.condition}) OR
(if {?hal} <> "" then {ArrivingTrips.hall}={?hal} else {other.condition}) OR
(if (hasvalue({?tim})) then {ArrivingTrips.arrivalTime}={?tim} else {other.condition}) OR
({?d1} = {ArrivingTrips.arrivalDate})
```

This formula will evaluate if any of the conditions are met. If you need a combination of conditions met, then you will have to join them by using AND.

Comment: unfortunatly, it didn't work too :( , what i want is to escape the false conditions , this is what i want only